# Using Spring Security together with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-security, grails-2.0

I wanted to use MongoDB in my Grails application and also Spring Security. I generated both User and Role classes with the `s2-quickstart` command. I added an `id` property to all my classes of type `ObjectId` as it says in many blog articles.

It does work, but one method bothers me a little:

```
    // SecUser.groovy (generated by s2-quickstart)
def beforeUpdate() {
    if (this.isDirty('password')) {
        encodePassword()
    }
}
```

The method `isDirty()` seems to be unavailable in a MongoDB environment. It works fine using Hibernate. This is a bug filed under http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMONGODB-114

Is there any way to get around this method? As far as I understand, it checks if the password was modified and then encodes it again.

Wouldn't it be possible to do this manually? For example, if I have a *User profile* page which has the password field included, I just encode it again on save?

I'd really like to use both Spring Security and MongoDB together and I'm sure this method won't stop me. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason why you can't create your own UserDetailsService which loads the hashed password from Mongo, then use a PasswordEncoder in your AuthenitcationManager. This will tell Spring to hash the password entered by the user before comparing it to the value you retrieved from mongo.

I can't comment on the Grails aspect but we are using Spring security and hashed passwords with Mongo. We actually have a custom password encoder that uses an iterative hash/salt so I'm sure what you want is possible :)

Comment: What is the `UserDetailsService` for? I saw this class in an example application on GitHub, but it wasn't generated. Is this just a nice thing to have? I currently don't see any benefits in using it. I just threw away the `before...()` methods and created a new `User` object and set the salted/hashed password "by hand" and not by the `User` object itself. Works like a charm. I guess a lot of things are done by the Grails plugin or Spring Security itself automatically that doesn't need to be explicitly configured.

Comment: Finally marked your answer as correct, since implementing the password hashing yourself on every save or update of the User is the only way to go with Grails and MongoDB, since `isDirty()` is only supported in Hibernate. Doesn't hurt much though